# Brand new to C++. Handling user input

Tags: c++

I wrote a few applications in VB.NET a decade ago, and am now trying to teach myself C++.

I am trying to figure out how to properly handle user input and stumbled across the following link which discusses the topic and the creation of GetInteger function and the like for other data types.

[GetInteger()](http://www.keithschwarz.com/cs106l/fall2010/course-reader/Ch3_Streams.pdf) @templatetypedef

I am getting an error; "identifier 'GetLine' is undefined.  Perhaps this is an overloaded function that returns a stringstream that was defined in another lesson?  Any direction would be much appreciated.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    int GetInteger() {
        while (true) {
            stringstream converter;
            converter << GetLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The article you linked provides a definition for it's `GetLine` function. It's not a standard function. Edit : See page 38 Edit 2 : From page 27 : *"In CS106B/X, we provide the `simpio.h` header file, which exports the input functions `GetLine`,
`GetInteger`, `GetReal`, and `GetLong`. "* so it looks like you are expected to get this header and include it in your program.

Comment: C++ is a very complex and nuanced language.  If you want to learn it, I suggest you get yourself a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and learn form their.  This is something they will cover in the book.

Comment: Thanks.  I ordered a C book and then decided to go with C++.  I'll check the list you've linked and order a C++ book.

Comment: I think the 2 ***Introductory, no previous programming experience***  books are a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be complete to what was said in the comments, your code has to provide GetLine as well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string GetLine() 
{
    string result;        
    getline(cin, result);        
    return result;
}

int GetInteger() {
    while (true) {
        stringstream converter;
        converter << GetLine();
    }
}
```

But I also recommend getting yourself a good book or in depth C++ tutorial.
You might find that C/C++ is quite different from the .net ecosystem languages

Comment: Thanks.  So simple once you posted the code. LOL.  I'm going to order a book as you've suggested.